# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x\sqrt{\cos 2x}\sqrt[3]{\cos 3x}}{x^2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to evaluate:

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x\sqrt{\cos 2x}\sqrt[3]{\cos 3x}}{x^2}.$$

Here's what I did. We know that as soon as ${x\to 0}$ 
$$1 - \cos x = \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4)$$
Therefore
$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4)$$
Now we apply this to cosines in limit
$$\cos 2x = 1 - 2x^2 + O(x^4)$$
$$\cos 3x = 1 - \frac{9x^2}{2} + O(x^4)$$
Then use equality
$$ (1 + x)^n = 1 + xn + o(x)$$
It yields us
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1 - (1 - \frac{x^2}{2})(1 - x^2)(1 - \frac{3x^2}{2})}{x^2}$$
After simplification 1s cancel and we get $-(-1/2 - 1 - 3/2) = 3$.

Comment: You can't write that $1-\cos(x)\rightarrow\dfrac{x^2}{2}$. A function can only tend to a number.

Comment: Thanks, I meant that both sides are equivalent

Comment: Then don't write that $\cos x\sim1-x^2/2$, as it's true but useless (it's true also that $\cos x\sim 1+100x$ or actually $\cos x\sim1+\epsilon(x)$ with any function $\epsilon(x)$ such that $\epsilon(x)\to0$ when $x\to0$. Equivalent means something precise, and it's not what you seem to think it is.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut How do you suggest me write it?

Comment: The correct notation is $\cos x=1+x^2/2+o(x^2)$, or $\cos x=1-x^2/2+O(x^3)$ (and actually even $\cos x=1-x^2/2+O(x^4)$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in a neighbourhood of the origin $\cos(x)= 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$, it follows that $\cos(2x)= 1-2x^2+o(x^2)$ and $\cos(3x)= 1-\frac{9x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$. Since $\sqrt{1+z}=1+\frac{z}{2}+o(z)$ and $\sqrt[3]{1+z}=1+\frac{z}{3}+o(z)$ we get that:
$$ \cos(x)= 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2),\quad \sqrt{\cos(2x)}= 1-x^2+o(x^2),\quad \sqrt[3]{\cos(3x)}= 1-\frac{3x^2}{2}+o(x^2) $$
hence their product behaves like $1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+1+\frac{3}{2}\right)x^2=1-3x^2$ and the wanted limit is $\color{red}{\large 3}$.

The neglected parts in the above manipulations are $o(x^2)$, hence they do not affect the final outcome.

Comment: Can we show that without Taylor series? The problem precedes this topic and I'd like explanation to be on the same level. Maybe, we can use o-notation and properties?

Comment: $\sim$ here is used with the asymptotic meaning: you may read $g(x)\sim 1+A x^2$ as $g(x)=1+ A x^2+o(x^2)$

Comment: @VasylGreen: and you do not strictly need Taylor series to show that $$\sqrt{1+z}= 1+\frac{z}{2}+o(z),\qquad \sqrt[3]{1+z}= 1+\frac{z}{3}+o(z).$$

Comment: Usually, the $\sim$ notation is reserved to the definition $f(x)\sim g(x)$ iff $f(x)=g(x)(1+\epsilon(x))$ with $\epsilon(x)\to0$. Hence $\cos(x)\sim 1$, or $\cos x\sim1+ax$ for any real $a$. Why not use the $o$ notation in the first place?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: it was faster to just use $\sim$, but anyway, answer modified.

Answer (score 2):

The $x^2$ at the denominator suggests we can use the fact that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
Rewrite the numerator as
$$
(1-\sqrt{\cos2x}\sqrt[3]{\cos3x})+\sqrt{\cos2x}\sqrt[3]{\cos3x}(1-\cos x)
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{\cos2x}\sqrt[3]{\cos3x}(1-\cos x)}{x^2}=
\frac{1}{2}
$$
we are reduced to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{\cos2x}\sqrt[3]{\cos3x}}{x^2}
$$
Let's retry the trick, rewriting the numerator as
$$
(1-\sqrt[3]{\cos3x})+\sqrt[3]{\cos3x}(1-\sqrt{\cos2x}\,)
$$
Now
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{\cos2x}}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}4\frac{1-\cos2x}{(2x)^2}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\cos2x}}=
4\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=1
$$
This leaves us with
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{\cos3x}}{x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}9\frac{1-\cos3x}{(3x)^2}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{\cos3x}+\sqrt[3]{\cos^23x}}=9\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{3}{2}
$$
Thus our limit is
$$
\frac{3}{2}+1+\frac{1}{2}=3
$$

Alternative method. Define
$$
g_n(t)=\log\sqrt[n]{\cos(n\sqrt{t})}=\frac{1}{n}\log\cos(n\sqrt{t})
$$
defined in a suitable neighborhood of $0$.

For $t\ne0$, the derivative is
$$
g_n'(t)=
\frac{1}{n}
\frac{1}{\cos(n\sqrt{t})}
(-\sin(n\sqrt{t}))\frac{n}{2\sqrt{t}}
$$
and the limit at $0$ is easily seen to be $-n/2$, so by l'Hôpital the function $g_n$ is also differentiable at $0$.

The function you have to compute the limit of is even, so we can as well compute the limit from the right and do the substitution $x=\sqrt{t}$, so we have
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1-\cos\sqrt{t}\sqrt{\cos(2\sqrt{t})}\sqrt[3]{\cos(3\sqrt{t})}}{t}
$$
which is the negative of the derivative at $0$ of the function
$$
f(t)=\cos\sqrt{t}\sqrt{\cos(2\sqrt{t})}\sqrt[3]{\cos(3\sqrt{t})}
$$
and we can do the logarithmic derivative, so
$$
\log f(t)=g_1(t)+g_2(t)+g_3(t)
$$
and so
$$
\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}=g_1'(t)+g_2'(t)+g_3'(t)
$$
Since $f(0)=1$, our limit is
$$
-f'(0)=-(g_1'(t)+g_2'(t)+g_3'(t))=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{2}=3
$$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for any integer $N\geq 1$,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\prod_{n=1}^N \sqrt[n]{\cos(nx)}}{x^2}=\frac{N(N+1)}{4},$$
because
$$\prod_{n=1}^N \sqrt[n]{\cos(nx)}=\prod_{n=1}^N \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{(nx)^2}{2}+o(x^2)}=\prod_{n=1}^N \left(1+\frac{(nx)^2}{n2}+o(x^2)\right)\\
=\prod_{n=1}^N \left(1+\frac{nx^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)=
1+\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N n+o(x^2)=1+\frac{N(N+1)}{4}\cdot x^2+o(x^2).$$

Answer (score 0):

When we do the Tayor series expansion of the numerator, we don't care about the $x^3$ and higher powered terms.  They are all going to 0.  I am going to drop them as I go.

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac {1 - (1 - \frac {x^2}{2})(1-2x^2)^\frac12(1-\frac {9x^2}{2})^\frac 13}{x^2}$

Now do the binomial expansion and continue to drop the $x^3$ and higher powered terms.

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac {1 - (1 - \frac {x^2}{2})(1-x^2)(1-\frac {3x^2}{2})}{x^2}$

Multiply it out, (still dropping high powered terms)

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac {1 - (1 - (\frac 12+1+\frac 32) x^2)}{x^2}$

And evaluate.

$ 3$